# Compare microphone input with audio file

Tags: javascript, html, api, audio

I have been throwing an idea around that requires comparison of client microphone input and an existing wav file.

I would like to compare audio waves, client side if possible, returning a percentage of accuracy and was hoping this could be accomplished with the new HTML5 getUserMedia API. However I have not been able to find a viable solution thus far.

A prime example would be a graphical representation of an analogue tuner, I would like to compare mic input to audio recordings of different notes and keys.

Can this be achieved client side via JavaScript?  And if not, are there any APIs out there that are already doing this?

Comment: This is an audio feature extraction problem: direct comparison of the waveforms will give you very little information of any use.   Feature extraction in general is a hard problem. 
There have been a large number of questions on SO concerned with approaches to building an instrument tuner. These might be a good starting point.